# Laravel Error loading vagrant file

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have a freshly installed Laravel. I did a `vagrant destroy --force` before installation.

Every time I run anything using vagrant on my laravel project directory, I get this error.

There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

> Path: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Sites/project-flyer/Vagrantfile
>   Line number: 12
>   Message: LoadError: cannot load such file -- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Sites/project-flyer/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb
>   exit 1

Now, I've checked, looking for `homestead.rb` but `vendor/laravel/homestead` folder doesn't exist. I'm lost.

Comment: Which version of Laravel do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is a broken [homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead) installation in your directory. You could do:

- Deinstall the existing homestead with `composer remove laravel/homestead`
- Reinstall homestead with `composer require laravel/homestead --dev`
- Initizialie homestead and Vagrant configuration `php vendor/bin/homestead make`

For details you can also consult the [homestead documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead#per-project-installation).

Comment: Hey, @codeedge. Thanks for the reply.

Okay, when I do this:
composer install laravel/homestead --dev

It spits out this:
Invalid argument laravel/homestead. Use "composer require laravel/homestead" instead to add packages to your composer.json."

Comment: Instead, I added it on my composer.json file:
Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/homestead dev exists as laravel/homestead[2.0.x-dev, dev-master, 4.0.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.7, v2.0.8, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2] but these are rejected by your constraint.

Comment: @user3809980 yes it is 'composer require' instesd of 'composer install'. Can you show your complete composer.json?

Comment: php vendor/bin/homestead make results in **Could not open input file: vendor/bin/homestead**